# Can battery levels ever be reliably read while it is powering an embedded system

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, adc, avr, battery-operated

I have an AVR microcontroller (atmega168pa) powered through two AA battery cells. When I read the battery voltage while it is not hooked up to the bread board, the voltage might read as 3.14 on a DMM. After hooking it to the system (uc is reading the battery voltage through ADC every 1 second), if I read the battery voltage now with a DMM, the voltage reads as 2.98 something.

The whole use case is just to blink an LED when the battery is close to critically low voltage.

I am just a hobbyist and was wondering if you guys could shed some light on it. The ADC is reading voltage even lower. I have put a voltage divider on the ADC0 pin. R1 is 39k while R2 is 10k to get the input voltage less than 1.1V. I then use internal band-gap reference voltage of 1.1V to measure the voltage on ADC0. It consistently under reports voltage by at least 0.1V. There are some board discussions about input impedance for which I put a capacitor between ADC0 and ground yet the readings are still off.

How should one go about this?

Comment: Refer to AN2447 by Microchip. It explains how to correctly measure battery voltage even without using any pin at all. For improved accuracy this might take some sort of calibration. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00002447A.pdf

Comment: Have you measured how much your 1.1V reference actually is?

Comment: @Justme I didn't check. I assumed it to be actually 1.1V. Now that you have said that I will check that too.

Comment: @NStorm the paper says that VCC can be read with this formula:

Vcc = 1024 * Vbg / RESadc

The code implementation of this is shown as:

Vcc_value = ( 0x400 * 1.1 ) / (ADC_RES_L + ADC_RES_H * 0x100)

Can you explain why the ADCL and ADCH are added and multiplied with hex 0x100?

Comment: As others have mentioned, you're doing fine, especially for your very limited use case. However, if you ever need to accurately know the State-of-Charge of a battery in the future a Coulomb Counting Battery Gauge is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary: Batteries are super difficult to measure. It sounds like you're already getting a decent measurement. It's probably best to stick with that and move on.**

In the title of your question you are asking about measuring the battery *level* (which I will interpret as "how much capacity is left"), but you are talking about measuring the battery *voltage*. It's certainly natural to think of "battery level" and "battery voltage" as being the same thing, but they're not.

All batteries have an internal resistance, so the voltage reading will change when the battery is supplying some current. Worse yet, the (no-load) voltage of the battery will change as the battery discharges, *and so will the internal resistance*. Even worse yet, the way these change will depend on how the battery is discharged (high load vs low load, pulsed vs continuous load), and the battery behavior will change over temperature, if it is allowed to rest a while, and so on.

Old saying: "a battery is a nonlinear function of *everything*".

But you can still come up with a rough estimate of when a battery is completely spent. Alkaline batteries have a discharge curve that gets steeper toward the end of life; for example consider this figure from [a TI app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva194/slva194.pdf):
[image: Alkaline battery discharge curve]

Here we can see that once the battery reaches end of charge its voltage starts to fall off pretty rapidly. And, visually you could make the assessment that once the cell voltage is below 1.0V then there's not really much useful life left anyway. (Some people use 0.9V or 0.8V; it depends on the application.)

So, in summary it's best not to worry about the 0.1V discrepancies you're seeing. Just set a threshold of somewhere like (2 x 0.9V) 1.8V as your "battery low" signal and that's probably all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, batteries have internal resistance. It will read lower voltage when current is consumed compared to no current being consumed, and your multimeter measurements confirm it.

The ADC input impedance is not a problem, because it is optimized for source impedance that are 10k or less, and since you have a 10k resistor and 39k resistor the impedance will be less than 10k for sure, about 8k.

The ADC measurement is also well within specs. The internal Vref is not 1.1V, it will be somewhere within 1.0V to 1.2V range due to manufacturing tolerances. That's +/- 9% tolerance.

If your multimeter measures 2.98V and your AVR measures 0.1V less, that's already 4% within the ideal value assuming your multimeter is ideal and has no tolerance error and your resistor divider is ideal without tolerance error.

Most likely you are using resistors with more than 0.1% tolerance and you don't know the multimeter tolerance, so measuring 0.1V difference is actually pretty good for a system with up to 9% tolerance just from the internal Vref.

For best results it is worth to check the ADC clock being in the specified 50 to 200 kHz range.

Comment: How did you arrive at 8k impedance?

Comment: The ADC input is driven by two resistors, a 10k and a 39k resistor. I also estimate your Vref is about 1.14 V.